# MS Access - scan for a key words using a list of key words contained in another table

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access I am looking for a way to scan a table for an unlimited number of key words and phrases without having to hard code hundreds of like statements.  For example, I would like to use one "like" statement and have it call the key words and phrases I want to check for from a reference list contained in another table.  Anyone done anything like that? If this can be done without "like" statement, I am open to suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I just did something similar but using an = statement, so what I'm suggesting works with a 'LIKE'.  Loop through your reference table records and create a string that keeps adding the `"AND phrase LIKE '*" & refString & "*'"` string to a superlong SQL statement.   Attach this WHERE portion to the SELECT/FROM portion of your string (after removing the first AND) and execute that string to return the records you want.